# Prolog return a list which contains only elements which are equal to head of the list

Tags: prolog

Hello I would like to ask a doubt I have with the following code:

```
principio([],[]).
principio([H],[H]).
principio([H,_|_],[H]).
principio([H,H|C],P) :-
    principio([H|C],R),P=[H|R].
```

I would like a way to get from:

```
?- principio([222,333,101,202,12,222,13,222],X).

X = [222,222,222]
```

But in this moment I get just the head:

```
X = [222]
```

So, to keep it clear I'd like: ***all successive occurrences of the first element*** as a list.

My doubt is what does this assignment `P=[H|R]` why not to put just:

```
principio([H,H|C],P) :-
    principio([H|C],P)
```

Also, how would you try to modify this to get the result I asked for?
Thank you

Comment: Remove these cuts, they will not help you with this at all.

Comment: You need to make a clear statement about what you expect, without referring to the concrete implementation. I am still unsure what you want. Every third element? Or all successive occurrences of the first element?

Comment: `Also I have another doubt and as we can only post from time to time` that's not how this site works. Questions are expected to contain one question only. The site is striving to be an archive of questions and answers for future generations and that only works if there's exactly one question that matches the title.

Comment: To reviewers: OP did edit question accordingly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is two ways how you can narrow down the problem. 1st, start from an unexpectedly failing query. 2nd, start from a query that should fail but rather succeeds.

### 1st Diagnose unexpected incompleteness

#### Determine a most specific failing query

```
?- principio([222,333,101,202,12,222,13,222],[222,222,222]).
   false.
```

#### Generalize the query

... as much as possible. I could do this manually, or I could let Prolog do the work for me. Here I use [`library(diadem)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/diadem.pl):

```
?- use_module(diadem).
   true.
?- principio([222,333,101,202,12,222,13,222],[222,222,222]).? Gen.
   Gen = principio([222, 333|_], [_, _|_])
;  Gen =  (dif(A100, B100), principio([A100, B100|_], [_, _|_]))
;  ... .
```

In other words: Not only does your original query fail, but also this generalization fails! Here, we only insist that the first two elements are different, and that the resulting list contains *at least* two elements — no matter which!

```
?- dif(X, Y), principio([X,Y|_],[_,_|_]).
```

#### Generalize your program

```
:- op(950, fy, *).
* _P_0.

principio([], _/*[]*/).
principio([_H], _/*[H]*/).
principio([H,_|_],[H]).
principio([H,H|C],P) :-
    * principio([H|C],R),
    * P=[H|R].
```

The error must reside in the little remaining part of your program. No need to read any further!

The problem is that for a list starting with two different elements you only have the clause `principio([H,_|_],[H]).`.  So this part has to be generalized somehow.

### 2nd Diagnose unexpected unsoundness

Another way of finding the error would be to start with the unexpected solution:

```
?- principio([222,333,101,202,12,222,13,222],[222]).
true.         % incorrect !!
```

And then reduce the size of the query as much as possible.

```
?- principio([222,222],[222]).
true.         % incorrect !!
```

Now, specialize your program inserting **`false`** as long as above query succeeds:

```
principio([],[]) : - false.
principio([H],[H]) :- false.
principio([H,_|_],[H]).
principio([H,H|C],P) :- false,
    principio([H|C],R),
    P=[H|R].
```

The remaining visible part is the culprit! We have to revise it. What it says is:

> Any list starting with two elements corresponds to the list with the first element only.

```
principio([],[]).
principio([H],[H]).
principio([H,D|Xs], [H|Hs]) :-
   dif(H,D),
   principio([H|Xs],[H|Hs]).
principio([H,H|Xs],[H|Hs]) :-
   principio([H|Xs],Hs).
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the very nice answer provided by @false (+s(0)), I would point out the possibility to use DCGs for the task. They usually yield easily readable code when describing lists (see comments beside the grammar rules):

```
principio([H|T],Hs) :-
   phrase(heads([H|T],H),Hs).

heads([],_H) -->          % in the empty list
   [].                    % there's no element matching H
heads([H|Xs],H) -->       % if the head of the list matches H
   [H],                   % it's in the list
   heads(Xs,H).           % same for the tail
heads([X|Xs],H) -->       % if the head of the list is
   {dif(X,H)},            % different from H it's not in the list
   heads(Xs,H).           % same for the tail
```

Thus your example query yields the desired result:

```
   ?- principio([222,333,101,202,12,222,13,222],X).
X = [222,222,222] ? ;
no
```